# Hide value in pivot without affecting grand total

Tags: excel, pivot

Please help me to hide value in excel pivot without affecting the subtotal or grand total.

I tried to select or clear the *Subtotal filtered page items* in pivot option /* as recommended by Microsoft */ but this is grayed out.

Could some one help me on this.

Comment: If you want to just make the _values_ invisible you could change the _font_ color to match the _fill_ color.

Comment: Thanks Clif good thought. But I wanted to hide or remove a particular row lable and its value without affecting subtotal or grand total.